# Finding the number of Maxima

Tags: sequences-and-series

The given sequence $\frac{1000^n}{n!}$ , where n = 1,2,3.....

a.) Does not have a maximum.

b.) Attains a maximum at exactly one value of n.

c.) Attains a maximum at exactly two values of n.

d.) Attains a maximum for infinitely many values of n.

My Attempt : I tried to use calculus to find out the point where the derivative of this function would become zero. 
After using quotient rule , I came to the following equation :
$ log1000 = \sum_{n=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} $

I know that as n tends to infinity the RHS will diverge. Hence I came to the conclusion that there exists one value of n for which the following equality will hold.
But the answer marked is says equation has two maxima's , how ?

Please tell me , If I my approach is wrong , or whether I have erred in calculations. Also if you could guide me on how to get the correct answer that would be great too.

Comment: Hint: Look at the **ratio** of consecutive terms.  No calculus.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{n} 1/n$ is not good use of notation

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas Although I understood the ratio of consecutive terms reasoning , I would still like to know what was wrong in my approach . I am mystified by the fact that having two maxima's means that for two different values of n the series 1/n converges to log1000 . How is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the terms of the sequence be $s_n = \frac{1000^n}{n!}$. Consider the ratio of successive terms. It's easy to show that

$\frac{s_{n}}{s_{n-1}} = \frac{1000^n}{n!}/\frac{1000^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1000^n}{1000^{n-1}}/\frac{n!}{(n-1!)}=\frac{1000}{n}$

So the sequence must be increasing when $\frac{1000}{n}>1$, and decreasing when $\frac{1000}{n} < 1$. So if there are any maxima, they have to happen around the point where that inequality flips.

Comment: But this will also lead to only one maxima won't it ? ( Since the only maxima we will get will be for n = 1000 )

Answer (score 1):

Exactly two points:

- $n=999$
- $n=1000$

---

Elaboration:

- $n<999\implies\frac{1000^n}{n!}<\frac{1000^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$
- $n=999\implies\frac{1000^n}{n!}=\frac{1000^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$
- $n>999\implies\frac{1000^n}{n!}>\frac{1000^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: Thank you , for the answer .It will be really appreciated if you could tell me what went wrong in my approach. Since I am mystified by the conclusion that my approach has lead me too i.e. that there are two distinct values of n for which the series converges to log1000. @ barak manos

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava: I don't understand your question. First of all, the original question states "sequence", not "series" (which means the sum of a sequence). So what do you mean by "the series converges"??? Second, whether it's "sequence" or series", the term "convergence" refers to infinity (i.e., as $n$ goes to $\infty$). So what exactly do you mean by "two distinct values of $n$ for which the series converges to $\log1000$"???

Comment: There might be two distinct values of $n$ for which the sequence is equal to $\log1000$, but is has nothing to do with convergence, and in any case, this value is not necessarily the maximum value of the sequence (which is what the question at hand is all about). Please correct me if I'm wrong.